# Wider dropdown based on text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following script:

http://jsfiddle.net/oshirowanen/6SUwR/3/

How do I give the drop down section a dynamic width based on the characters in the dropdown?  For example, if "navigation 1" was "this is the first item in the navigation",  How do I make the width of the whole dropdown wider automatically, but without affecting the size of the navigation button which causes the dropdown the dropdown when mouseover'ed?

Basically, I don't want to text to wrap in the dropdown, but at the same time, I don't want to button for the dropdown to go wider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

http://jsfiddle.net/lukemartin/W9TzP/

Basically just set the .container's width to auto, and then took the background-color off of the .container and put it on each individual .nav_item. Also added some floats and clears so correct widths are set.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

you could use this jQuery code

```
 var maxWidth = 0;
    $(".container a .nav_item").each(function() {
        if (($(this).width())> maxWidth) {
            maxWidth = $(this).width();
        }
    });
    $(".container").width(maxWidth+10);
```

the above will find the biggest width, and will apply it on the `.container` (+10 is for the padding you have).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6SUwR/23/