# Select2 wider dropdown

Tags: css, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

Is it possible to have wider dropdown with latest select2 version? I was trying to do what is here suggested [Wider dropdown based on text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978732/wider-dropdown-based-on-text) but that is for older version and it doesn't work.

Basically what I want is that the dropdown would dynamically get the widest width of the longest text I have (maybe some css max-width would be in place though). I'm using the basic markup and stylings of select2 v 4.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

for select2 v4.0 you can set the dropdown to a specified width on opening of the dropdown (note this is only when the list opens below I prevented the list from opening above)

```
    $(".select2-container").bind('DOMSubtreeModified',function()
    {
       if ($(".select2-dropdown--below").length > 0 ) 
    {
        $(".select2-dropdown--below").css("width","300px"); 
    }
    });
```